# Soft/Weak key MapMAker with equals for key

Tags: java, guava

I need a Concurrent Hash Map with Weak or Soft keys were the equality is equals and not ==.

For this kind of keys, google collection chooses == by default.

Is there a way to override this choice? How should I proceed?

Best regards,

Nicolas.

Comment: Please modify the question to describe in detail what you are really trying to accomplish, not just a particular missing feature that you believe would help you do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in google-collections. You can't do it in [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) either, currently. However, they have added an [Equivalence](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) interface and the implementations you'd expect for it (`equals`, `null`-aware `equals` and `==`) recently and it seems like they *might* allow you to specify what `Equivalence` should be used for keys/values in the future (see [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=337)). `MapMaker` code seems to be undergoing some changes at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.WeakHashMap`, wrapped with a call to `Collections.synchronizedMap()`

It won't be as fast as a ConcurrentHashMap if thread contention is significant. But it has the behaviour you want.